# Game Center, can't sign up IOS 6.1.6 Ipod touch 4th gen

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, game-center

I have an Ipod touch 4th Gen on ver 6.1.6, it is not jailbroken. Whenever I try to sign in I get these results

[image: Logging in]

[image: loading]

[image: And nothing]

I don't know why it won't work, I have tried factory resetting it, using 3 different Wi-Fi networks, and a bunch of other stuff, but it won't get past that third picture.

I have a old Game Center account, and I can sign in with it, but I refuse to use it because the nickname is hella embarrassing, when I sign in with it I can play games fine, however there is one thing when I try clicking on "account: (my old email)" then "View Account" and then it just loads, then gets stuck on that same green screen I would get stuck on when trying to sign in with my new Apple ID

Edit: I am editing it to show you all what I meant in my last paragraph

Signed in with my old account

[image: Signing in]

Selecting "view account"
[image: View Account]

and then I get that same blank screen, and it doesn't load anything, I waited for 5 minutes.

So I think both of them stem from the same problem, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The dashed circle near the WiFi symbol in the third screenshot means it is still loading something. Does that persist indefinitely?

Comment: No it goes away really quickly, usually stays for less then 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Just had this problem with an iPod running iOS 6.1.6.  Here are the steps I followed to fix it.

1. Log into Game Center on a friend's device (must be iOS 7 or greater).
2. Accept the terms and conditions and create Game Center profile.  Once profile is created, log out of Game Center.
3. On the iOS 6 device, sign out of your Apple account used by your device and then sign back in.
4. Launch Game Center and sign in.

Basically, iOS 6.1.6 is having issues when new Game Center users need to create their profile for the first time.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer, that really sucks though, I never use macs, don't like them, and so I guess I am just screwed, thanks apple :)
Edit: actually, could probably borrow my brothers Iphone, and create the profile on there, sign out, and then sign in on mine, stupid solution but it would probably work

Answer (score 0):

I was getting exactly the same issue on my son's 4th Gen touch with IOS 6.1.6.
This was a new Games Center ID.

The fix was to log on with a friends Macbook and connect to Games Center on that.
It then let me set-up his nickname and complete the account.
I then logged out of Games Center.

Following this Games Center on the ipod has been working fine.